# random forest for density estimation using sklearn

Tags: random-forest, scikit-learn, density-estimation

I want to use or extend sklearn-randomForest for density estimation. I don't know to tackle it. I read A. Criminisi and his team work on random forest as a unified framework where they first introduced this idea. What I got are:

- the information gain is computed using an entropy of gaussian or another distribution
- Training data that reached each node are modeled by a single gauss distribution which is used to model the distribution at each leave (gaussian also).

So how to concretely used these to extend sklearn-randomForest code?

Answer (score 1):

sklearn's random forest doesn't currently support density estimation, and I don't think there's any easy way to hack it without significant changes to the random forest code.

The code to start looking at is [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/master/sklearn/tree), but your best bet is probably to ask for advice on [the mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/scikit-learn/mailman/scikit-learn-general/) about the best way to go about implementing it.

Here isn't really the right place, because none of the regulars are scikit-learn developers (as far as I know), the question-answer format isn't super appropriate, and it's not really [on-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) since it's about implementation only.